# Flask - Flashing with HTML Class

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a list of items. So do make it simple let's say my list is

`[id, title, picturePath]`

I'm trying to achieve flashing out a [Bootstrap Card Deck](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/) using `from Flask import Markup`.

Here's my code to flash the card out.

```
payload = Markup(f"<div class='card'>
                    <div class='card-body'>
                     <img src='{item[2]}' class='card-img-top'>
                     <h5 class='card-title'>{item[1]}</h5>
                     <p class='card-text'>asd</p>
                    </div>
                   </div>")
flash(payload)
```

And here's my code in the HTML page using Jinja2

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="flashes">
        {% for message in get_flashed_messages()%}
            {{ message|safe }}
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

And... This is the result I get:
[image]

However, My expected Results is:
[image]

And that expected result is done by just putting in the html elements in the html code. It suppose to be in a 3x3 grid.

It seems as if flashing out these things using Markup causes it to loose its html class or i guess the ... formating? Not sure. But Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: what wrong with your result ? What did you expect? Did you check source code in web browser? Maybe it generate correct HTML but problem is in different place - ie in CSS?

Comment: @furas I want it displayed in a 3x3 grid like the one found on the bootstrap documentations link. Its suppose to. But I notice 2 things so far, 1: If In my HTML code, theres the `<div class="flashes>` it appears like the result i showed. Without the div, it just appears ... chaotically. 2: Most of the bootstrap CSS codes are overwritten e_e.

Comment: @furas I've edited my question adding my expected results.

Comment: first I would check if CSS is really loaded. If you changed CSS code then problem can be in new CSS.

Comment: @furas I haven't written any CSS codes yet. The only thing my website is using is bootstrap 4.3.1. And I'm pretty sure it loaded the css because when i inspect element the css codes shows up

Comment: first I would use DevTools in Chrome/Firefox (tab Network) to see if bootstrap CSS is loaded. Beside I don't see `<link>` (in jinja) which loads bootstrap.

Comment: @furas Sorry wait what? Am I missing something? What do u mean the `<link>` in jinja? I have a base.html which has bootstrap and this page im working on extends the base.html

Comment: to load `bootstrap` to browser which will display this page you need `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">` in HTML generated by `Jinja`

Comment: even if you have `base.html` which should load bootstrap I would first check in DevTool in tab Network if this bootstrap is loaded correctly - with status code 200 (eventuall `304` if browser has it in cache)

Comment: @furas yes i just checked it shows status code 200 `bootstrap.min.css` so its loaded

Comment: I have no more idea. Maybe you would have to show full code so we could run it and see problem.